# Developing a Web Page to Post Text into Facebook

Tags: javascript, fbml

I am trying to develop a web page which will post some text from textbox to my fb timeline.
In fb developer account ,I have got method for that .It is working but it will always post a url link with my textbox text.
I don't want to include this url in timeline post.
Here is my javascript code

```
  FB.ui({
            method: 'share',
            caption: 'Your Comment',
            description: $('#TxtCmnt').val(),
            href: 'google.co.in',
            message:'This is for testing purpose'
        }, function (response) { });
```

I want to exclude href. Here without href ,code won't work.
Any remedy???

Comment: Why are you using a share dialog (which is expressly for sharing links) when you're apparently trying to post a message to your feed?

Comment: You need to use the `/post` endpoint of the Graph API: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.7/post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check for facebook api.Facebookclient() will instantiate an object that will do the rest job.
https://facebookapi.codeplex.com/

Answer (score 0):

I just test this "me/feed?link=&picture=&message=test" in graph api explorer and it worked.
So leaving them blank and using /feed should work for you.